# Question on "semi-linear" dynamical systems

Tags: linear-algebra, ds.dynamical-systems

I am interested in understanding the convergence properties of a dynamical system at zero. We know that a dynamical system of the form $x_{k+1} = Ax_{k}$ where $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix without eigenvalue that is exactly equal to one, converges to zero if the initial condition is orthogonal to the unstable eigenvectors (those with eigenvalues greater than one). Consider any unit vector $\hat{n}$. I would like to understand the convergence properties of the following system:

$$x_{k+1} = (I -\hat{n}\hat{n}^T \times \textbf{1}_{\hat{n}^TAx_k>0})Ax_k,$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix and $\textbf{1}$ denotes the indicator function.
Thank you!